# SpreadsheetDocument.Open Sharepoint File

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to open a web SharePoint Excel File using `SpreadsheetDocument.Open()` method.

I am able to open the file using a browser (URL something like https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/XXXXTeam/Shared%20Documents/General/Test%20Files/excel.xlsx?d=yyyy)

but in the C# code I get an exception:

> "Could not find document"

Of course, there is MFA on the site.

What do I need to do to be able to access (read-only) the excel file?

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research , you can call the `OpenSpreadsheetDocumentReadonly` method to open a Spreadsheet Document for Read-only Access, for example:

```
    OpenSpreadsheetDocumentReadonly(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sheet10.xlsx");

public static void OpenSpreadsheetDocumentReadonly(string filepath)
    {
        // Open a SpreadsheetDocument based on a filepath.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
        {
            // Attempt to add a new WorksheetPart.
            // The call to AddNewPart generates an exception because the file is read-only.
            WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

            // The rest of the code will not be called.
        }
    }
```

Please refer to the document: [Open a spreadsheet document for read-only access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-open-a-spreadsheet-document-for-read-only-access#sample-code).

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved .If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes this works for local files, but does not seem to work on SharePoint files